# How do I make a JNI hello world program in Android Studio?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-studio-4.0

I am currently using Android Studio 4.0

In the earlier versions of Android Studio there was a check box in the app creation wizard I could set to make a hello world program using JNI

It used to give a java project for the UI, and a cpp file as  JNI sample along with the CMakeLists.txt file. I don't know since which version of Android Studio it went away, but it's not there any more. How do I get this option back? Or can I download the hello world JNI template program from somewhere? I want it to use cmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Android Studio 4.0` click to `File -> New -> New Project` scroll to bottom and select `Native C++`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can start from one of the official samples, `File ⇒ New ⇒ Import Sample…`. The one you referred to is `Ndk ⇒ Hello JNI`.